# Is it possible to insert two child Nodes with same name but different Attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-serialization, xsd

I would like to create an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
<languages>
    <language id =1>English</language>
    <language1 id=2>Slovenian</language1>
</languages>
<strings>
    <line id=1>
        <string lid=1>camera</string>
        <string lid=2>kamera</string1>
    </line>
    <line id=2>
        <string lid=1>lens</string>
        <string1 lid=2>leka</string1>
    </line>
</strings>
</text>
```

I am trying with the following code in C# (Windows Forms Application):

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration xmldec = xmldoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
        xmldoc.AppendChild(xmldec);
        XmlElement root = xmldoc.CreateElement("text");
        xmldoc.AppendChild(root);
        XmlElement lang = xmldoc.CreateElement("languages");
        XmlElement languages = xmldoc.CreateElement("language");
        languages.SetAttribute("id", "1");
        languages.InnerText = "English";
        lang.PrependChild(languages);
        languages.SetAttribute("id", "2");
        languages.InnerText = "Slovenian";
        lang.PrependChild(languages);
        XmlElement lines = xmldoc.CreateElement("strings");
        XmlElement line = xmldoc.CreateElement("line");
        XmlElement lineinner = xmldoc.CreateElement("string");
        line.SetAttribute("id", "1");
        lineinner.SetAttribute("lid", "1");
        lineinner.InnerText = "some english text";
        line.AppendChild(lineinner);
        line.SetAttribute("id", "1");
        lineinner.SetAttribute("lid", "2");
        lineinner.InnerText = "some slovenian text";
        line.AppendChild(lineinner);
        lines.AppendChild(line);
        root.AppendChild(lang);
        root.AppendChild(lines);
        Metodi.SerializeXMLToXML(xmldoc);
```

And i end up with the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
    <languages>
        <language id="2">Slovenian</language>
    </languages>
    <strings>
        <line id="2">
            <string lid="2">some slovenian text</string>
        </line>
    </strings>
</text>
```

After every next AppendChild() replaces the previous is there any way to achieve this??

Comment: What do you mean with "AppendChild() replaces the previous"?

Comment: when i use this code:
    `line.SetAttribute("id", "1");`
    `lineinner.SetAttribute("lid", "1");`
    `lineinner.InnerText = "some english text";`
    `line.AppendChild(lineinner);`
    `line.SetAttribute("id", "1");`
    `lineinner.SetAttribute("lid", "2");`
    `lineinner.InnerText = "some slovenian text";`
    `line.AppendChild(lineinner);`
I do not get both children but only the last - i.e. the slovenian text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-initialize it every time is one solution:

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration xmldec = xmldoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
xmldoc.AppendChild(xmldec);
XmlElement root = xmldoc.CreateElement("text");
xmldoc.AppendChild(root);
XmlElement lang = xmldoc.CreateElement("languages");
XmlElement languages = xmldoc.CreateElement("language");
languages.SetAttribute("id", "1");
languages.InnerText = "English";
lang.PrependChild(languages);
languages = xmldoc.CreateElement("language");
languages.SetAttribute("id", "2");
languages.InnerText = "Slovenian";
lang.PrependChild(languages);
XmlElement lines = xmldoc.CreateElement("strings");
XmlElement line = xmldoc.CreateElement("line");
XmlElement lineinner = xmldoc.CreateElement("string");
line.SetAttribute("id", "1");
lineinner.SetAttribute("lid", "1");
lineinner.InnerText = "some english text";
line.AppendChild(lineinner);
line = xmldoc.CreateElement("string");
line.SetAttribute("id", "1");
lineinner.SetAttribute("lid", "2");
lineinner.InnerText = "some slovenian text";
line.AppendChild(lineinner);
lines.AppendChild(line);
root.AppendChild(lang);
root.AppendChild(lines);
Metodi.SerializeXMLToXML(xmldoc);
```

Nodes can only have one parent, hence your problem. <del>A nicer way to resolve this, though, might be to use XML literals.</del> It has come to my attention that C# does not support XML literals. This doesn't change the fact that you can write this in a nicer way using XML serialization or loops and such.

Comment: C# does not support XML literals.

Comment: @SLaks: Oh, that's odd. I thought it did. Well, score one for VB ;)

Comment: @minitech - the native xml support is the only, only, only, only redeeming thing I've ever seen about that language.  If that makes you angry note that I +1'd your answer :)

Comment: @AdamRackis: It doesn't make me angry, everybody says that :) But I do disagree. I mean, VB doesn't make you repeat anything... it doesn't require a trailing `Select x` in LINQ... it doesn't have unboxing issues... `For` loops can be more efficient... you don't need to place `@` in front of things that you need to escape. But this isn't the time ;) And thank you.

Comment: @minitech - you don't need a trailing select x?  That's actually really cool.  I understand why we don't have native xml (would interfere with generics), but the select x thing is interesting.

Comment: @AdamRackis: I can't tell if you're being sarcastic about the trailing `select x` or not :) But I don't think XML would interfere with generics. XML can't follow any type name as far as I know, so it should be obvious enough to the compiler. I hope they have it in C# 5.

Comment: @minitech - not sarcastic - I try to be in the small % of people who aren't dicks on the internet :)  It is neat to me that you guys don't need a select x, but then again, assuming you use dot notation, you don't need it in c# either.  I don't know the details about `<>` interfering with generics, but I heard the compiler team said they couldn't do it, and I know those guys are a LOT smarter than me, so I take their word for it :)

Comment: @AdamRackis: Oh, dang. Well, the `Xml.Linq` namespace is pretty great by itself :)

Comment: @AdamRackis: In C# you can avoid the trailing `select x` by using traditional method calling instead of sql-like syntax sugar. Anyway, it's still cool for VB.NET.

Comment: @minitech: Can I ask the question "what unboxing issues does C# have"?

Comment: @DannyChen - for sure - like I said, dot notation instead of that clunky, ugly query notation.

Comment: @DannyChen: I guess that's not really relevant anymore with the advent of generics, but [this fails in C#](http://ideone.com/N6if7) because the `unbox` IL command is used as opposed to the `callvirt` used by VB.NET.

Comment: @AdamRackis: VB also supports exception filters and indexed properties and named interface implementations.  The `Handles` keyword is also nice.

Comment: @Slaks - maybe I should give it more love than I do :)